# Event Firing When Not Called

Tags: vb.net, events

I am working on a project in VB using VS 2008 and and am having trouble with events firing when they are not called.

I have a textbox called **txtIMItem** and a button called **btnIMCancel**. When I press enter in the textbox, the **textChanged** event fires which is fine. Immediately after it is done executing (I'm tracing in debug) it skips to the **btnIMCancel_Click** event which redirects the page, causing the rest of my page to not function properly. There doesn't seem to be any connection to these two events and I'm not sure the reason this is happening. Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
 Partial Class EditItemsMold
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim mMIIX As New clsMold_Item_Insert_Xref

    Protected Sub PopulateAllMolds()
        Dim oMld As New clsMolds, oMld2 As New clsMolds, li As New ListItem

        If Not oMld.ReadAll(True) Then
            lblIMCaption.Text = oMld.LastError
        End If
        ddlIMMold.Items.Clear()
        li = New ListItem
        li.Text = "Select"
        li.Value = 0
        ddlIMMold.Items.Add(li)
        For Each oMld2 In oMld.mCollection
            li = New ListItem
            li.Text = oMld2.MoldNumber
            li.Value = oMld2.MoldID
            ddlIMMold.Items.Add(li)
        Next
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If IsPostBack Then

        Else
            PopulateAllMolds()
            ddlIMMold.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub txtIMItem_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtIMItem.TextChanged
        Dim oI As New clsItems

        oI.ItemNumber = txtIMItem.Text
        If Not oI.Read(oI.ItemNumber, True) Then
            txtIMItem.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            lblIMCaption.Text = "Item Cannot Be Found"
            lblIMCaption.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            btnIMUpdate.Enabled = False
            Exit Sub
        Else
            txtIMItem.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
            lblIMCaption.Text = "Item Found"
            lblIMCaption.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
            lblIMDescription.Text = oI.Description
            btnIMUpdate.Enabled = True
            ddlIMMold.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ddlIMMold_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlIMMold.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim oIns As New clsInserts, oIns2 As New clsInserts
        Dim li As New ListItem
        If Not oIns.ReadAllForMold(ddlIMMold.SelectedValue) Then
            lblIMCaption.Text = "Could not read inserts for mold: " & oIns.LastError
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For Each oIns2 In oIns.mCollection
            li = New ListItem
            li.Text = oIns2.InsertNumber
            li.Value = oIns2.InsertID
            ddlIMInsert.Items.Add(li)
            ddlIMInsert.ClearSelection()
        Next
        If oIns2.InsertID = Nothing Then
            ddlIMInsert.Items.Clear()
            li = New ListItem
            li.Text = "No Insert"
            li.Value = 0
            ddlIMInsert.Items.Add(li)
            ddlIMInsert.SelectedValue = 0
        End If
        ddlIMInsert.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnIMUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnIMUpdate.Click
        mMIIX.ItemNumber = txtIMItem.Text
        mMIIX.MoldID = ddlIMMold.SelectedValue
        mMIIX.InsertID = ddlIMInsert.SelectedValue
        mMIIX.InsertName = ddlIMInsert.SelectedItem.Text

        lblIMCaption.Text = ""
        If Not mMIIX.SaveUpdate Then
            lblIMCaption.Text = "Could not update Item's Mold record: " & mMIIX.LastError
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Response.Redirect("ScheduleJobs.aspx")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnIMCancel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnIMCancel.Click
        Response.Redirect("ScheduleJobs.aspx")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnCatch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCatch.Click
        Dim i As Int16
        i = 0
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is the vb code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="EditItemsMold.aspx.vb" Inherits="EditItemsMold" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Edit Item's Mold</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:inherit;">
    <form id="frmEditItemsMold" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="alignCenter"><asp:label ID="lblIMCaption" runat="server" Text=""></asp:label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td class="alignLeft"><asp:Label  ID="lblIMItem" runat="server" Text="Item: "></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtIMItem" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblIMMold" runat="server" Text="Uses Mold: "></asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIMMold" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblIMInsert" runat="server" Text="And Insert: "></asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIMInsert" runat="server" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack = "true"> </asp:DropDownList></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alignCenter" colspan="4"><asp:label ID="lblIMDescription" runat="server" Text=""></asp:label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="alignRight"><asp:Button ID="btnIMUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" Enabled="false" /><asp:Button ID="btnIMCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /></td>         
                <td><asp:Button ID="btnCatch" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Button></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you tried to change the Click event to MouseClick?

Comment: It doesn't look like mouseClick is an option for the button but I tried it anyways and no luck.

Comment: does it happen when you 'blur' from the textbox.. or just when you hit enter? What is inside scripts.js? a validator?

Comment: debug again and post what the sender object is that is invoking the control's click event..

Comment: looks like the sender for the cancel button is {Text = "Cancel"}

Comment: Also it doesn't happen when I blur. And scripts should be removed. It has a drag and drop plug-in that is relevant to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have you Cancel button set as the form or container's default button...?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There's no indication that it is set as default although I could easily be overlooking it. Where could I find this indication? I've looked in the properties panel.

Comment: I believe if there is only one button inside a container, then that becomes the default action when hitting enter (inside said container). You can probably specify your own call to be the default call for that container, even if its a dummy, as  to not fire the Cancel button by default.

Comment: There is also a default button property for all (most ?) server side controls, accessible from the IDE properties section.

Comment: it would be odd if the form choose the 2nd button instance as the default button though.. still..

Comment: @BrettCaswell , looks like the first button is disabled, so it may indeed take the Cancel button as default.. `<asp:Button ID="btnIMUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" Enabled="false" />`

Comment: makes sense to me.. pressing enter on the textbox is raising the default button click event.. the default button is likely btnCancel because btnIMUpdate is disabled..

Comment: It looks like that's the case. I had a btncatch there hoping to intercept the behavior but because it was after the cancel button, the default remained btnCancel. So I moved btnCatch before the cancel button and made it visible and now the btncatch event is firing (which essentially does nothing). I appreciate all of your replies. Thanks for your time and help.